# What functional space does $\mathbb{X} = \{0\}$ belong to?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, proof-writing

In a lot of proofs regarding spaces, the example $\mathbb{X} = \{0\}$ is given as the trivial case.

Why is that $\mathbb{X} = \{0\}$ is a linear/normed/Banach/Hilbert... space when it is essentially only consisting of one element?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? It satisfies the axioms of the given spaces. Besides, we want the orthogonal complement, kernel and image of maps, etc. to be linear, normed, etc. spaces, or at least (sidestepping notions of closure, etc.) close to them.

Comment: Why not? There's nothing about the number of elements in the definitions. Define $||x||=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb X$ and it's easy to see you have a complete norm (if $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence then $x_n=0$ and hence $x_n\to0$). Define the inner product of any two elements to be $0$ and it's easy to verify that you have a Hilbert space. Etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematics is a lot about outsmarting your definitions. Namely, "show where it says that you can't do that". This is why so many definitions in mathematics have "trivial" examples, sometimes to the point where they can be a cumbersome addition to each proof when first learning the subject.

If the definition of a vector space is such that nowhere it is required to be nontrivial, then a trivial vector space is still a vector space. If $V$ is a vector space, then $\{0\}=\operatorname{span}(\varnothing)$. Again, nowhere it says that you shouldn't consider the span of the empty set.

You can now either argue directly that $\{0\}$ can be endowed with various structures (e.g. normed space), or you can now argue that if $V$ was normed, then $\{0\}$ is a subspace of $V$ and so it is normed, and if $V$ was complete, then $\{0\}$ is a closed subspace so it is also complete.

Comment: Just curious: How does one define $\operatorname{span}(\varnothing)$?

Comment: Well, the empty sum is $0$. So just the same as you would in any other way. Only you only get $0$.

Comment: Is there some consistency reason for defining $\sum_{v\in\varnothing}v=0$? I'm thinking of something like $\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}}A:=\{x\in X:\exists A\in\mathcal{A}:x\in A\}$. There it would be that $\bigcup_{A\in\{\,\}}A=\{x\in X:\exists A\in\{\,\}:x\in A\}=\varnothing$.

Comment: Well, $\sum_{i\in I}v_i-v_j=\sum_{i\in I\setminus\{j\}} v_i$. So $\sum_{i\in\varnothing}v_i=\sum_{i\in\{i\}}v_i-v_i=0$.

Comment: Aha nice thanks!!